# How can I make a script in python to reload an app in qlik cloud

Tags: javascript, python, data-analysis, qlikview, qliksense

At this moment I'm trying to reload a Qlik app through a python script, but I had a few problems, I'm gonna explain the things I already tested, but if someone knows how can I solve that, I will appreciate it a lot

- The first thing I tried, was the "[reloads API](https://qlik.dev/apis/rest/reloads)" from qlik, to do this you have to send a request with the app id, and with the parameter "Partial" true or false, but even more important, you have to send with this request a JSON web token, so I was searching how to obtain the jwt of qlik and I found this page: "https://qlik.dev/tutorials/create-signed-tokens-for-jwt-authorization", I created all as the page said, and finally I make this code in javascript to test, but this doesn't work:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const uid = require('uid-safe');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const https = require('https')

const payload = {
  jti: uid.sync(32), // 32 bytes random string
  sub: '(id of my user that appears in assignment users)',
  subType: 'user',
  name: '(Name of my user)',
  email: '(email of my user)',
  email_verified: true,
};

const privateKey = fs.readFileSync("path/certificate.pem");

// I don't know the meaning of that 'kid and issuer have to match with the IDP config' 
// audience has to be qlik.API/jwt-login-session
const signingOptions = {
  keyid: I put = 'my-custom-jwt',
  algorithm: I put = 'RS256',
  issuer: '(hostname)',
  audience: I put = 'qlik.api/login/jwt-session',
};

const myToken = jwt.sign(payload, privateKey, signingOptions);

const qlikUrl = "(hostname)"

const data = JSON.stringify({"appId": "(appId)", "partial": true})
const options = {
  hostname: qlikUrl,
  port: 443,
  path: '/api/v1/reloads',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ myToken
  }
}

https.request(options)
req.write(data)
```

- The second thing I did was, try to use the "qsAPI" library of python to connect to my qlik and reload an app specifying their id by a method of this library, but I don't understand what I have to put here, and in the [documentation](https://github.com/rafael-sanz/qsAPI), doesn't say nothing about what's the meaning of the parameters, except ('hostname'). The problem is in the method to do the connection because I have to do this:

```js
qrs = qsAPI.QRS(proxy='hostname', user=('yor_domain', 'username', 'password'))
```

I say that because if I go to the python IDE, this show which parameters I have to put, and these are different, now I have to put this:

```js
qrs = qsAPI.QRS(proxy='hostname', user=('userDirectory', 'userId', 'password'))
```

- I don't know where I can find the user directory because I don't know
  what it is.
- The user id (I'm guessing it's the user id that appears in "mapping
  users").
- The "password", is no problem

But still have an opportunity, because I can connect to Qlik through python if I find where I can download the certificate authentication of a user, but I don't know where is it in qlik cloud.

Can someone help me, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally have the solution of that as Stefan Stoichev said before publishing this post, the `qsApi` seems to be a python library for `Qlik Sense Enterprise on Windows`, and the correct library for the `Qlik Cloud` is `qsaas`, but I'm going to explain every step because I don't want that any person of this world suffer this.

First of all, you have to create an `API KEY`, in `Qlik Cloud`, `IMPORTANT`, you have to save the api_key code that appears in a green text box when you created successfully your `API KEY`, save this as your dear friend because you will need this code in the future

Subsequently, you have to create a new python code as this:

```js
from qsaas.qsaas import Tenant
import JSON

api_key = <API_KEY>

q = Tenant(api_key=api_key, tenant=<hostname>,
           tenant_id=<tenant_id>)

q.post('reloads', json.dumps({'appId': 'dbf3e4ce-c6b3-4190-876c-c443a8691fa6'})))
```

Don't worry my dear friend if you don't know where is it, the 'hostname' and the 'tenant_id' are in qlik cloud, here is a little tutorial for you:

- First login to your qlik
- Then click on your profile photo
- Click in `about`, and there you have these two data information

Answer (score 3):

I havent tried with Python (only with JS/TS) but the approach should be the same.

Couple of things:

- imo instead of web token you can try with API Key (for a start). [Managing API keys -> Generating an API key from the hub](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Admin/mc-generate-api-keys.htm).
- the second point is that `qsAPI` seems to be for `Qlik Sense Enterprise on Windows` and not for SaaS.
- the only Python lib dedicated for Qlik SaaS (that im aware of) is [qsaas](https://github.com/eapowertools/qsaas). Havent used it myself ... just found it on GH
- and a bit of a warning regarding the `partial: true`. Please make sure that you really have to use [partial reload](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/May2022/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/PartialReload.htm). Partial reloads have a specific use case and be careful when using them ... just saying :)

Comment: Thank you very much, thanks to you I created a script in python with the qsaas library, and it works fine, I'm going to publish the solution, but without your comment,
it would have cost much more, thanks

Comment: Not a problem. Happy to help and glad that it worked for you :)